# Scrapy: nested selector : the child selector run on all page not on parent selection

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I would like to save in a `.jl`, all the data associated with a item (let say a person) from a webpage that list a lot of persons. 
The parse should be something like this

```
for eachperson in response.xpath("//div[@class='person']"):
            person=myItem()
            person['name'] = eachperson .xpath('//h2[@class="name"]/text()').extract()
            person['date'] = eachperson .xpath('//h3[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
            person['address'] = eachperson .xpath('//div[@class="address"]/p/text()').extract()
            yield person
```

But I get a bug. I have adapted my spider to the page http://quotes.toscrape.com/ (cf below) so you can reproduce it.

```
import scrapy
import requests

class TutoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tuto"
    start_urls = [
            'file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/data.html'
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quotechild in response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
            print("\n\n", quotechild.extract())
            print("\n\n", quotechild.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract())
```

The first print return what is expected, but the second print return all `span class="text"` of the whole page as a `list`, not just the one from `quotechild`.

I have followed the [https://doc.scrapy.org](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#nesting-selectors), and many other tuto, but I can't find what I am doing wrong.

I run on a local file because the original page on which I am working, render the html via javascript.
The `.hml` is simply the source of http://quotes.toscrape.com/

Example of first print:

```
<div class="quote" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Eleanor Roosevelt</small>
        <a href="/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt">(about)</a>
        </span>
        ...
    </div>
```

Example of second print (I expect only one of the item in the list at each print):

```
['“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”', '“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”', '“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”', '“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”', "“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.”", '“Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.”', '“It is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.”', "“I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.”", "“A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.”", '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting an xpath expression with `//` will make it start matching at document root, regardless of which element you use it on.

To make the xpath relative to the element (only searching its descendants), start the expression with  `.//`

```
>>> len(quotechild.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()'))
10
>>> len(quotechild.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()'))
1
>>> quotechild.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
'“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'
```

Comment: thanks for that! Interresting. But how can scrapy "knows" what the document root is when only `quotechild` is passed down. quotechild is only a couple of div, not the whole document

Comment: `quotechild` is a scrapy selector, which is an object that is aware (among other things) of the document it is a part of.

Comment: Oh okay, it makes sense. Thanks a lot!